# What is the correct way to clean up an embedded dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We're using the [powerBi JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/releases) to embed dashboards in our app using something similar to:

```js
powerbi.embed(embedElement, embedConfig);
```

As a part of the app's lifecycle, it's likely we'll want to un-embed the dashboard, and I was wondering what the correct way to do this is so that the powerBi client knows about it, so we prevent potential memory leaks?

Can we simply remove the `embedElement` from the DOM, or empty it? Or is there a method the client exposes to do this more explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `powerbi.reset(embedElement)` as described in:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/master/src/service.ts#L404

This basically unloads the iframe and its content

Comment: I've looked every where for this. Thank you.